# Change position of table in beamer presentation: Table right under table caption

Tags: tables, beamer, positioning

I created a table:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\title{Title}
\date{Nov. 17, 2023}
\author{}

\usetheme{quito-light}
\usepackage{booktabs} % package for table
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx} % package for units and numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}
  \begin{table}
    \tiny
    \caption{table title}
    \begin{+array}{delimiter = {right=\rbrace, left=.},column{2} = {mode={imath}}}
    \midrule
      a & a \sim \qty{10}{m}\\
      b & b \sim \qty{5}{s^{-1}}\\
      c & c \sim \qty{10}{m.s^{-1}}\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{+array}
    Description
  \end{table}
\end{frame}
\note{}

\end{document}
```

How can I adjust the table position? The left side of the table should be directly below the caption.

Comment: Please note that we can't compile your code if you use a custom theme which we don't have. Either check if your question makes sense without it and leave it out or, if it is essential to your question, include it in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The only real effect of the `table` environment in beamer is to centre the table. If you don't want this, don't use the `table` environment and the table will automatically align with the surrounding text:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\title{Title}
\date{Nov. 17, 2023}
\author{}

%\usetheme{quito-light}
\usepackage{booktabs} % package for table
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx} % package for units and numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}

  \begingroup
    \tiny
    \captionof{table}{table title}
    \begin{+array}{delimiter = {right=\rbrace, left=.},column{2} = {mode={imath}}}
    \midrule
      a & a \sim \qty{10}{m}\\
      b & b \sim \qty{5}{s^{-1}}\\
      c & c \sim \qty{10}{m.s^{-1}}\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{+array}
    Description
  \endgroup
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]